# C++ LinkedList read access violation error

Tags: c++, crash

i am trying to write my own LinkedList Application in C++. Right now i am stucked at a point where i need some help. My Application is triggering an access violation error and i dont know why.
I appreciate any kind of help. When i delete the method "printList()" after liste -> remove(0) (right now this method is working with only 1 node in the list) its working, but i want to see the output. If i insert the method printList() once again, its crashing again.

Here is my code:

LinkedList.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    std::cout << "Die Liste wurde aus dem Speicher gelöscht.";
}

int LinkedList::append(const char* text) {
    //new Node
    Node* node = new Node();
    node->setData(text);
    node->setNext(NULL);

    //temp pointer
    Node* tmp = head;
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        //List empty && set first node to head
        head = node;
    } else {
        //list not empty, find the end of the list
        while (tmp->getNext() != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->getNext();
        }
        tmp->setNext(node);
    }
    return 0;
}

int LinkedList::remove(int p) {
    int counter = 0;
    //temp pointer
    Node* node = head;
    delete node;
    return 0;
}

void LinkedList::printList() {
    Node* node = head;
    if (node == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Empty";
    } else if (node->getNext() == NULL) {
        //only one node in the list
        std::cout << node->getData() << " --> NULL" << std::endl;
    } else {
        do {
            std::cout << node->getData() << " --> ";
            node = node->getNext();
        } while (node != NULL);
        std::cout << "NULL" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

node.cpp

```
#include "node.h"
#include <iostream>

Node::Node() {
    //NOTHING
}

Node::~Node() {
    std::cout << "Node aus Speicher gelöscht.";
}

void Node::setData(const char* d) {
    data = d;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* n) {
    next = n;
}

const char* Node::getData() {
    return data;
}

Node* Node::getNext() {
    return next;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

int main() {
    LinkedList* liste = new LinkedList();
    liste->printList();
    liste->append("10");
    liste->printList();
    liste->remove(0);
    liste->printList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `remove` function is not implemented correctly. You are deleting the head node in each call without assigning a new head or searching for whatever you were meant to be removing.

Comment: I know that this remove function wont work with a larger list. in my case its only intended (for now) to work with 1 element due to locating the error. If i am not wrong, i am deleting the dynamically created node with every call, not the head or?

Comment: In that case at the very minimum set the `head` pointer back to null (preferably nullptr) in your `remove` method.

Comment: Thanks, that was the mistake. After setting head = Null after the delete call in the remove function, my code is working. But why did this error come up? Did i delete my head?

Comment: yes. The fact you assigned it to another variable obscures that fact somewhat.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 'limited scope' `remove` function you delete the head node (via the `node` variable). This means that next time you try to print the list, you are trying to use a value that has been deleted and therefore are invoking undefined behaviour.

In the interim before you implement your `remove` function for the general case you should set the head pointer to null.

```
int LinkedList::remove(int p) {

    if(head){
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }

    return 0;
}
```